# Prove that removing k − 1 edges from a tree T results in a graph which has k components, by induction

Tags: graph-theory, trees

T is a tree with an amount of components, I need to prove this by induction. The base case $k=1$ works as removing $1-1=0$ edges keeps the number of components the same.

Comment: I'm trying to do the inductive step of k>= 1 but I am having difficulty showing this

Comment: No induction needed, a Tree on k vertices has exactly k-1 edges, if you remove them there is no edge left and you end up with k components.

Comment: @Luke, why would $T$ have exactly $k$ vertices?

Comment: well, you're right. Let me rephrase: every edge lies on a path from some vertex r (root) to a leaf. if we delete this edge, there's not a path to that leaf anymore, and we get two trees (or a forest with two components), since our Graph was a tree. Now we can do this again on the subtrees. Every deleted edge gives one more component

Comment: I assumed that, because Lara said that in the base case her Tree has exactly one edge. Which isn't true if $k \neq n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to do it with induction:

Base Case: k = 1. Clear.

Step: k-2 -> k-1

Remove k-2 edges from the Tree, by Induction hypothesis, you get k-1 components. Now each of this components is a tree itself. Now remove one edge from one of those trees. Again by induction hypothesis, you get 2 components, so all in all you get k components if you remove k-1 edges.

Comment: If you're going to do it like this you need to do the case $k=2$ as an additional base case, since you are using that case in the final step.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime could you elaborate? I only use the base case k = 1 in the last step if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In the last step you remove $1$ edge and claim this gives you $2$ components by induction. This is the case $k=2$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime You are indeed correct, I'm sorry for that little mistake, thank you for pointing it out!